# Как заменить значения NULL с одной таблицы на значения с другой таблицы при FULL OUTHER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, bigquery

Проверьте пжл правильность запроса SQL.
У меня есть таблица (`Table_1`). Вот пример данных:

```
Id  Value   Info
1   NULL    Test_1
2   12      Test_2
3   21      NULL
4   NULL    Test_4
5   12      Test_5
6   7       Test_6
7   21      Test_7
```

И есть 2-я таблица (`Table_2`).
Вот такая:

```
Id  Value
1   32
12  NULL
4   NULL
12  31
```

Я хочу сделать следующий `SELECT`:

1. Если `Id` в таблице 1 совпадает с `Id` в таблице 2, и значение поля `Value` в таблице 1 `NULL`, то я его заменяю на значение `Value` с таблицы 2.
2. Если какое-то `Id` из таблицы 2, не встречается в таблице 1, то я добавляю это значение в SELECT. Если какого-то поля не существует, то я его заменяю на NULL.
3. Если какое-то `Id` из таблицы 1 не встречается в таблице 2, я оставляю запись так, как есть.

Вот мой код:

```
SELECT Table_1.Id, Table_1.Value, Table_1.Info
CASE 
    WHEN Table_1.Value IS NULL THEN Table_2.Value ELSE Table_1.Value
END AS Value,
FROM Table_1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_2
ON Table_1.Id = Table_2.Id
```

Правильно ли я решил задачу? 
Спасибо)

Comment: Вообще-то есть функция COALESCE()...

Comment: +1 за COALESCE. Ее надо использовать и вместо `Table_1.Id` в SELECT - иначе будет много Id с значением NULL. Например `COALESCE(Table_1.Id, Table_2.Id) AS Id`. 
Еще делается предположение что Id в таблице 2 уникальны. А что если не так? :)